# Nim Subtraction Game Variant

Tags: puzzle, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I recently read about the Nim Subtraction Game.
I have a variant: Suppose you have $N$ stones and two players Alice and Bob, who can choose to pick either 1 stones or $K$ stones. If Alice plays first, when will she lose?
I think the answer is when ($N$ mod $K)=1$, Alice would lose.
Am I correct?

Edit: I am wrong. Could anyone provide an optimal solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a standard game (the player who has no legal move loses) then Alice certainly wins when $N=1$, so your expression is not correct in that particular case, though it is correct when $N=k+1$.

Alice also loses when $N=2$, if $k\gt 2$, and so on. So there are parity issues.

As far as I can tell from the patterns:

- If $k$ is odd then Alice wins when $N$ is odd and loses when $N$ is even.
- If k is even it seems to get more complicated.  Write $N$ as $a(2k(k+1))+bk+c$ with $0 \le c \lt k$ and $0 \le b \lt 2(k+1)$. Then:

  - Alice wins if $b-c$ is even and $2\le b-c \le k+2$ or if $b-c$ is odd and either $b-c \lt 2$ or $k+2 \lt b-c$.
  - Alice loses if $b-c$ is odd and $2\le b-c \le k+2$ or if $b-c$ is even and either $b-c \lt 2$ or $k+2 \lt b-c$.

Comment: Ok, what's the solution?

Comment: Why not pick some $k$, Harsh, and then work out who wins for various small values of $N$, and see if you can find, and then prove, a pattern?

Comment: This is the what I am getting for k from 1 to 12:
A B A A B A B A A B A B. Can't find a pattern

Comment: For odd $k$ the position is very simple: is $N$ odd or even?.  For even $k$, there are a couple of layers of complexity.

Comment: Ok, This is too hard,I give up.

Comment: Wait isn't her losing and winning condition same in your answer?

Comment: @HarshAgarwal: well spotted - now they differ